# Filling an array in Swift with Firebase dictionary

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch data from Firebase and add it as a object in a Swift array but whenever I run the application the array prints out empty. When I put a `print` statement inside the observe each purse prints out like I want it to but the purse never gets appended to the array.

```
var purses = [Purse]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    fetchPurse(completion: {print(self.purses.count)})
}

func fetchPurse(completion: @escaping () -> ()){
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: "https://test-database-ba3a2.firebaseio.com/")
    let user = (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!
    let userRef = ref.child("users").child(user).child("devices")

    userRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
            let purse = Purse()
            purse.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
            self.purses.append(purse)
            completion()
        }
    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to print the array? You are populating the array in an asynchronous function, so if you try to observe it's values outside the completion handler, you will most likely print the array before it would get populated.

Comment: I am calling the array in a different function and am attempting to use the .count method to load a certain amount of table cells for my table view based on how many purses there are.

Comment: fetchPurse() should have a completion handler and you should call your other function from the completion handler.

Comment: Could you point me to somewhere I could learn how to do that? I've never really used completion handlers and don't know how to add one to my function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a misunderstanding of how async methods work.

If you use code like this:

```
//at this point purses is empty..
fetchPurse()
print("purses count = \(purses.count)")
```

You will always see an empty purses array.

The problem is that the `fetchPurse()` function uses the Firebase function `observe`, which is asynchronous. It requests that Firebase run the code you pass as your `with:` closure when a new entry is added. The `observe` function returns immediately, and invokes the closure you pass to it as some future time when FireBase adds a new child object.

As a result, your `fetchPurse()` function also returns before the new purse object is added to your array of purses.

As @DávidPásztor said in his comment, you should refactor fetchPurse to take a completion handler that gets called when the purses array is updated:

```
func fetchPurse(completion: () -> ){
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: "https://test-database-ba3a2.firebaseio.com/")
    let user = (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!
    let userRef = ref.child("users").child(user).child("devices")

    userRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
            let purse = Purse()
            purse.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
            self.purses.append(purse)
            //This is the new line that calls your new completion handler
            completion()
        }
    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

And then you'd call it like this:

```
fetchPurse(completion: {
  print("purses count = \(purses.count)")
}
```

Comment: I updated the question with how I implemented your code and it is still showing a blank array. I included where I call the fetchPurse function as well